# Masstransit UseInMemoryOutbox not working with MultiBus Saga?

Tags: c#, state-machine, masstransit, saga

I implemented a custom activity for supporting multibus saga.
But I found an issue that is I received a published message from `SecondBus` before the state saga saves to Redis.
I think `UseInMemoryOutbox()` should handle this or i wrong.

```
public class TestActivity : Activity<SagaState, IFirstBusRequest>
{
    private readonly ISecondBus _secondBus;

    public TestActivity(ISecondBus secondBus)
    {
        _secondBus = secondBus;
    }


    public async Task Execute(BehaviorContext<SagaState, IFirstBusRequest> context, Behavior<SagaState, IFirstBusRequest> next)
    {
        var endpoint = await _secondBus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri($"queue:second-bus-request"));
        await endpoint.Send(new { }); // send immediately
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, it's a known limitation since the other bus instance is a completely separate bus, and isn't part of the outbox on the receiving bus.

If you need to involve the outbox, consider producing the message on the first bus, and have a consumer on that bus which only forwards that message to the other bus.

```cs
public class ForwardMessageConsumer<T> :
    IConsumer<T>
    where T : class
{
    readonly ISecondBus _bus;

    public ForwardMessageConsumer(ISecondBus bus)
    {
        _bus = bus;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<T> context)
    {
        var messagePipe = new ForwardMessagePipe<T>(context);

        await _bus.Publish(context.Message, messagePipe, context.CancellationToken);
    }
}
```

You could then just have an endpoint with those message forwarders on it:

```cs
x.AddConsumer<ForwardMessageConsumer<A>>()
    .Endpoint(e => e.Name = "second-bus-forwarder");
x.AddConsumer<ForwardMessageConsumer<B>>()
    .Endpoint(e => e.Name = "second-bus-forwarder");
```

And then, `ConfigureEndpoints` will put those consumers on a receive endpoint that will forward those messages to the other bus instance.

> The endpoint configuration is to put multiple consumers on the same queue, to avoid having multiple queues that just forward messages. It's assumed that `Publish` would be used from the activity.

Comment: I see, Then what is your suggestion for this scenario?